# Display Wordpress post list, sorted by an ACF field using a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I need to display a list of posts, ordered by an ACF date picker field (end_date). This is essentially an ‘ending soon’ list. I’m using the Divi theme and so would like to have this as a shortcode I can use to place the list anywhere within the builder.

My PHP is pretty basic so any help would be greatly appreciated.The below did not work, probably I’m sure for very obvious reasons that are above my ability.

```
function sort_query_order( $query ) {
    $currentdate = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));

$wp_query = new WP_Query(  array (
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query'=> array(
        array(
          'key' => 'end_date',
          'compare' => '>',
          'value' => $currentdate,
          'type' => 'DATE',
        )),
    'meta_key' => 'end_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'paged' => $paged,
    )
);
}
add_shortcode( 'ending_posts', 'sort_query_order' );
```

Comment: You are currently only making the database query there … but you are not doing _anything_ with the result. The data will not magically output itself, that is something _you_ have to implement. (And should you have no idea whatsoever how that works yet, then you should really do some more research and reading up on this first; if that in itself still needs explaining, this basically makes your question too broad for this place.)

Comment: from where `$paged` is coming as I don't see it in your function body either as a declaration or a global variable?